# Salvar variavel após refresh php

Tags: php, html, aplicação-web

Tenho um código que salva o POST de um form no html na variável $ID, no caso quando esse POST ocorre a página muda devido à essa variável, então gostaria de salvá-la de alguma forma para que eu não a perdesse quando dou refresh na página, para assim a página não mudar.

Comment: Voce pode armazenar usando `session` dessa maneira `$_SESSION['a'] = $ID`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para resolver o seu "problema" recomendo que você salve essa variável em uma sessão, ou até mesmo em um cookie para poder usá-la mais tarde.

Caso queria salvar em uma sessão, na página que pega os dados do `$_POST`, você poderia inserir esse código:

```
<?php
     session_start();//Colocar no inicio do código, se já não houver em alguma página que da include nessa
     //resto do código
     $id = $_POST['form'];
     $_SESSION['dados'] = $id;
     //resto do código
?>
```

Agora para recuperar esses dados em qualquer outra página, você faz o seguinte:

```
<?php
     session_start();//Colocar no inicio do código, se já não houver em alguma página que da include nessa
     //resto do código
     $id = $_SESSION['dados'];
?>
```

Lembrando que por ser `SESSION`, assim que o navegador for fechado, esse dados serão "removidos" da `SESSION`.

Caso queira saber sobre Cookies, esse [essa página](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.cookies.php).

Comment: $_SESSION['dados'] = $id; oque seria os 'dados' ?

Comment: É o nome que você está dando para os dados que ficarão armazenados nessa sessão, assim como um vetor associativo, na Sessão você pode colocar um "nome" para a posição em que ficará salvo algo. O nome 'dados' foi um titulo genérico que eu escolhi, só pra eu poder acessar o conteúdo armazenado futuramente. Digamos que eu vou armazenar o e-mail "user@email.com" na Session, nesse caso eu colocaria: $_SESSION['email'] = 'user@email.com';

Comment: no caso estou fazendo isso na mesma página, então eu devo colocar apenas um  session_start(); no começo certo?

Comment: Sim, corretíssimo.